# Pod installation not working due to node modules & podfile

Tags: ios, ruby, cocoapods, node-modules, rbenv

i am trying to setup my environment on my new computer( mac-m3) and i am trying to start a mobile application, when i try to run pod install i face these errors. My project uses:
node 14.20.0,
and: 3.3.0 (set by /user/.rbenv/version),
ruby 3.3.0 (2023-12-25 revision 5124f9ac75) [arm64-darwin23]
cocoapod version 1.14.3
react version 18.2.0
react-native version "0.67.9",
npm v8.19.4

'Log files:

## npm resolution error report

While resolving: react-redux@9.1.0
Found: @types/react@18.0.28
node_modules/@types/react
dev @types/react@"18.0.28" from the root project

Could not resolve dependency:
peerOptional @types/react@"^18.2.25" from react-redux@9.1.0
node_modules/react-redux
react-redux@"^9.1.0" from the root project

Conflicting peer dependency: @types/react@18.2.48
node_modules/@types/react
peerOptional @types/react@"^18.2.25" from react-redux@9.1.0
node_modules/react-redux
react-redux@"^9.1.0" from the root project

[!] Invalid `Podfile` file: /User/repo/app/node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods_utils/script_phases.rb:39: syntax error, unexpected <<
template =<<~EOS
^
/Users/baasandorj.l/Repos/OCH/kb-och/app/node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods_utils/script_phases.rb:40: unknown regexp options - ll
/Users/baasandorj.l/Repos/OCH/kb-och/app/node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods_utils/script_phases.rb:41: dynamic constant assignment
RCT_SCRIPT_POD_INSTALLATION_ROOT=$(pwd)
^
/Users/baasandorj.l/Repos/OCH/kb-och/app/node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods_utils/script_phases.rb:41: `$(' is not allowed as a global variable name
/Users/baasandorj.l/Repos/OCH/kb-och/app/node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods_utils/script_phases.rb:41: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input
RCT_SCRIPT_POD_INSTALLATION_ROOT=$(pwd)
^.

## from /User/app/ios/Podfile:1

## -------------------------------------------

> require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'

## require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

## -------------------------------------------

i tried deleting node modules, cocoapods, rbenv and reinstalled but its giving the same error and these are some versions of my environment, i even tried adding this line to my zshrc alias pod='arch -x86_64 pod' please help!!!